# Angular 16.2: Unknown browser query in new generated project

Tags: angular

With node.js v18.17.1 I installed angular cli with:
npm install --save @angular/cli

Then I created a new Angular project with:
ng new Tester

An angular project was created.
When I tried to run it with: ng serve I got:

```
    ./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
```

I did not modify any code in the generated code.

The output of: ng server --verbose is:
[verbose](https://pastebin.com/ZHBkTH7f)
Attached also : [package.json](https://pastebin.com/1LVHiZFK)

Can you please tell what went wrong ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: Use ng serve --verbose in order to get more details about the error.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My question now contains link to the output of : ng server --verbose.

Comment: Provide also the package.json dependency list.

Comment: Hi Jo. package.json attached.